# How to validate field with Codedom?

Tags: c#, validation, codedom

I am generating dynamic class with dynamic fields. I created fields but cant validate them. 
So far I did,

```
CodeMemberProperty property1 = new CodeMemberProperty();
property1.Name = "StringProperty";
property1.Type = new CodeTypeReference("System.String");
property1.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
property1.GetStatements.Add( new CodeMethodReturnStatement( new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), "testStringField") ) );
property1.SetStatements.Add( new CodeAssignStatement( new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), "testStringField"), new CodePropertySetValueReferenceExpression()));
```

this will generate class property but I need to validate it.
Expected output:

```
[Required]
public string FieldName {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be doing something like

```
CodeMemberField field = new CodeMemberField();
field.Name = "myField";
field.Type = new CodeTypeReference("System.String");
field.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private;
field.InitExpression = new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression(
    new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(
        new CodeThisReferenceExpression(),
        field.Name),
    CodeBinaryOperatorType.Assign,
    new CodePrimitiveExpression("Hello world"));

CodeMemberProperty prop = new CodeMemberProperty();
prop.Name = "myproperty";
prop.Type = field.Type;
prop.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
prop.GetStatements.Add(
    new CodeMethodReturnStatement(
        new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(
            new CodeThisReferenceExpression(),
            field.Name)));
prop.SetStatements.Add(
    new CodeAssignStatement(
        new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(
            new CodeThisReferenceExpression(),
            field.Name),
        new CodePropertySetValueReferenceExpression()));
prop.CustomAttributes.Add(
    new CodeAttributeDeclaration(
        new CodeTypeReference("Required")));
```

Is it doing what you expect ? What else do you mean by validation ?